# Is it possible to store a text in numeric field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

After many years working with Microsoft access, my mind comes with a question  kind "for dummies" apparently. I'm developing a database for students marks. What I want to do is once a students absent from the exam, then a text value (let say "Absent") should be stored in ExamMark column (type: number) instead of the mark which supposed to be a numeric value. Is it possible ?

Comment: technically no! but if your column is signed int, you could save -1 and represent this with "Absent"

Comment: Thank you Krish.
BTW, haven't got it !! how to represent it with "Absent" ?

Comment: add any sort of data validation like iif(exammark <= -1, "absent", exammark) and be sure no other function is accessing this field for their calculation. because other functions will fail when reading "Absent"

Comment: I strongly suggest that you do not add validation or formats to a table. Null should be valid for absent, forms, reports and queries can use Nz

Comment: Krish,
I tried your method, but having error "the value you entered does not meet the validation rule defined ......etc"

Comment: Thank you  Fionnuala ,
The curiosity is killing me to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a combobox field instead of a textbox field on your form.

Then create a lookup table for the marks with the following records

```
fldMarkId  fldMark
-1         Absent
 0           0
 1           1
```

Add all marks that can possibly be obtained to the lookup table. I suggest using an excel spreadsheet to generate that list then importing it into access.

Then if the student is absent you a numeric value (-1) is stored in your database but a text value is displayed